# get parameters from url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have some filters on my view and I want to get the parameters of my current URL and do something like edit any of my items in the page and go back with all the filters again after edit.

My example URL:

> localhost:8000/equipamentos/filtro?filter_descricao=APARELHO+ULTRASSOM&filter_patrimonio=0

Then I choose any item to edit and go to:

> localhost:8000/equipamentos/332/edit

After I change something I want to be redirected to the same URL with the filters in the beginning, like redirect and append filtro?filter_descricao=APARELHO+ULTRASSOM&filter_patrimonio=0

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $_GET['your_parameter_name']?

Comment: That would really help if you posted your code.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Input facade:

```
// All
$data = Input::all();

// $_REQUEST['foo']
$data = Input::get('foo');          // null if foo doesn't exist
$data = Input::get('foo', 'bar');   // if foo doesn't exist, the value is bar
```

Then you can handle the redirection in the controller on in a filter.

Comment: dont work because I'm not posting to edit, Is a get route just a link which I pass the id to edit view:         

<a href="{{ route('equipamentos.edit', array($equipamento->cod)) }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar" data-placement="top" class="legenda">
            <i class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="width: 41px; height:34px;"></i></a>

Comment: Did you try? [This method `Input::get()` is used for all request verbs (GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE)](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.html#method_get)

Comment: Yeah I set up the filter then edit, and used input get and receive a null value

Answer (score 0):

I just drafted out the code and it is working.

```
Route::get('/query', function() {

    return Redirect::route('result', Input::query());
});

Route::get('/result', [ 'as' => 'result', 'uses' => function() {

    return Response::make(Input::all());
}]);
```

Either `Input::all()` or `Input::query()` should work to retrieve `GET` parameters.

I'm using Laravel 4.2.11